# My if else statement is not working properly

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

We have to create a program in java that is kind of like a quiz, but my else statement keeps saying correct for every answer given. Here is what I have.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome:" + name );
        System.out.println("Please answer the following questions:\n" + "What is 4 + 6 \n");
        keyboard.nextLine();

        int x = 10; 

        if (x == 10){
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        }else{ 
            System.out.println("Incorrect!");       
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: With `int x = 10;` what did you expcet?

Comment: This is a joke, right?

Comment: Such demeaning responses. Last time I use this website, I'm sorry I'm not a full fledged programmer you have to start somewhere, and clearly this is not the website for it when I'm getting sarcastic answers by snobby programmers. Thanks though.

Answer (score 7):

You don't store the user response anywhere.

```
keyboard.nextLine();
int x = 10;
```

should be something like

```
int x = keyboard.nextInt();
```

or maybe something like

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```

Comment: I believe Java will throw a warning, but not an error, in a case like this question presented.  And if the author didn't know to examine the warnings as well as the errors, they might easily miss it.

Comment: @GlenH7 It warns if you use `final int x = 10;` (not with just `int x = 10;`, which isn't as surprising as I originally thought).

Answer (score 4):

Your code says

```
int x = 10; 

if (x == 10){ ...
```

You are checking to see if x equals 10 right after setting x equal to 10.